# Access an id of a user in a table from a controller

Tags: zend-framework

PHP, Zend Framework, Apache, MySql.

I want to edit a user in a list by clicking its corresponding edit button. 
when i click the edit button, the corresponding users id should be send to the controller from where it should be accessed. 
But I  cant seem to get the user id in the controller.

After getting the id , i want to populate the fields in edit.phtml with the data retrieved view model.

Since i cant access the id, i cant populate the fields.

The url is like /Sample/user/edit/2 where 2 is id of a user.

UserController.php

```
<?php

class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    protected $_user;

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
        $this->_user = new Application_Model_User();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    }

    public function listAllAction()
    {
        // action body
        $this->view->users = $this->_user->listUsers();
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {
        // action body
                if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
                {
                    $data = array(
                    'user_uname'    => $this->_request->getParam('uname'),
                    'user_pwd' => $this->_request->getParam('paswd'),
                    'user_address'  => $this->_request->getParam('address')
                     );
                    $this->_user->insert($data);
                }
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        // action body
        **$u_id = $this->_request->getParam('user_id');**
       // print_R("Hi ".$u_id);
       // exit;

        if($this->_request->isPost())
        {
            $u_id = $this->_request->getPost('user_id');
            //print_R("Hi ".$u_id);
            //exit;
        }

        else
        {
             **$this->view->user = $this->_user->getUser($u_id);**
        }
    }
}
```

Model class

```
<?php

class Application_Model_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name="tbl_user";

    public function listUsers()
    {
        // action body
        $sql = "select * from tbl_user";
        $result = $this->_db->query($sql);
        return $result->fetchAll();
    }

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        $query = "select * from tbl_user where user_id = ?";
        return $this->_db->fetchRow($query,array($id));
    }
}
```

ListUser.phtml

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <b><center>List of Users</center></b>
        <form name="list_users" method="post" action="">
            <table>
                <tr><th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>

                <?php foreach ($this->users as $usr): ?>
                <tr>
                     <td><?php  echo $usr['user_id'] ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $usr['user_uname'] ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $usr['user_pwd'] ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $usr['user_address'] ?></td>

                     <td><a href="<?php print $this->baseUrl() ?>/user/edit/<?php print $usr['user_id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>

                    <td><a href="<?php print $this->baseUrl();?>/user/delete/<?php print $usr['user_id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>

                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2><a href="/Sample/user/register">Add More Users</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit.phtml

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <form name="user_edit" method="post" action="<?php print $this->baseUrl(); ?>/user/edit">

       <b><center>Edit Profile</center></b>
        <table>

        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname1" value="<?php print $this->user['user_uname'] ?>"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="paswd" id="paswd1"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><textarea type="text" name="address" id="address1"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='edit_user' value='Update User'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><a href="/Sample/user/list-all">See All Users</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance..

---

I got the answer.

In usercontroller's editaction change the code $u_id = $this->_request->getParam('user_id'); to   $u_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

Comment: have you try $_POST['user_id'] to be sure that your parameters are sent from the browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small change needed: change the following line:

```
<td><a href="<?php print $this->baseUrl() ?>/user/edit/<?php print $usr['user_id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

to

```
<td><a href="<?php print $this->baseUrl() ?>/user/edit?user_id=<?php print $usr['user_id'] ?>">Edit</a></td>
```